# How to launch an AWS EC2 instance in a different language

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I'm trying to figure out how to launch an ec2 instance in a language other than English. I've tried setting different regions but that doesn't do any good. I've also found mentions of a language menu in the ec2 dashboard but again no luck.

Does anyone know how to do this or if it's possible? According to AWS documentation they support 19 different languages, Spanish been one of them, although I'm not quite sure what exactly that means.

Answer (score 2):

When you sign in, language selection will appear in the top right. When you sign in as IAM user, it will be at the lower half of the screen.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

There is a **language selector** in the AWS Management Console, in the bottom-left.

Strangely, some languages are greyed-out for me.

From [AWS Console Localization Enhancements](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2015/04/aws-console-localization-enhancements/) (Apr 21, 2015):

> The AWS Management Console now supports the Japanese & Simplified Chinese languages for 9 additional services: EC2, Auto Scaling, VPC, S3, CloudWatch, RDS, DynamoDB, IAM, and EMR. Customers who prefer to interact with the AWS Management Console in these languages can do so using a new Language Selector in the Management Console footer.